# Passing values from one model to another's form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models, `User`, `Service` and `Booking`. A user can book a service and this is done via a form under the `Booking` model.

I have a page for each service available for booking, with a link that says "Book Now" and redirects to the `new_bookings_path` so that a user can make a booking.

I want when the "Book Now" link is clicked, to be able to transfer the values of the service that are stored as records in the database (title, price etc), to the new booking form. So when a user is filling out a booking form, the are able to see which service they are actually booking.

This is my `_form.htm.erb` for the booking:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@booking) do |f| %>
    Booking Date: <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
    <br>
    Time start<%= f.time_select :timestart %>
    <br>
    Time end <%= f.time_select :timeend %>
    <%= f.input :address, label: "Address" %>
    <%= f.input :postcode, label: "Postcode" %>
    <%= f.input :suburb, label: "Suburb" %>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br><br>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

What I want to be able to do is place something like

```
<%= @service.title %>
```

at the bottom of the booking, although I am not sure how to access the title of the service that the user has clicked "Book Now" on.

Is it possible to get values of the service, and somehow access them under the bookings controller/_form when the "Book Now" link is clicked?

This is the "Book Now" Link:

```
<%= link_to "Book Now", new_booking_path %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass service id to the `new_booking_path` :

```
<%= link_to "Book Now", new_booking_path(service_id: @service.id) %>
```

within your `new` action in `BookingsController`, get the service:

```
def new
 @service = Service.find_by_id(params[:service_id])
 #your code goes here
end
```

Then you can do `<%= @service.title %>` in your form view page.